# Making enemy sensors not detect you immediately

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, 2d

I'm working on making a drone-type enemy that has a sensor that sticks out in front of it. I've been stuck on it for a while now, the problem is that I want the drone to not attack immediately after it detects the player, and for it to stay in suspicious mode a little while after the player leaves the drone's field of view. I'm relatively new to coding so my code is a bit of a mess.

```
void Update () {
    if (dTect == true && dTime > -1.6) {
        dTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (dTime < -1.5f) {
            aTak = true;
            animator.SetTrigger ("Host");
            animator.ResetTrigger ("Susp");
        } else {
            dTect = false;
            //animator.ResetTrigger ("Susp");
        }
    }
    if (dTect == false && dTime > 2.1) {
        dTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (dTime > 2) {
        aTak = false;
        animator.SetTrigger ("Susp");
        animator.ResetTrigger ("Host");
    }}  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")){
        dTime = 0;
        dTect = true;
        animator.SetTrigger("Susp");

        }
    }
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other){
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Player")) {
        dTime = 0;
        dTect = false;
    }
}
```

Any help or advice at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: well firstly, I think you're missing a `}`before your `OnTriggerEnter2D`

Comment: @code11 yeah, i accidentally cut that out when copying it into the question, sorry.

Comment: @FortyTwo The drone will detect the player properly, but i cant get it to undetect the player and go back into "incognito"  mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (dTect == true)
        {
            dTime += Time.deltaTime;
            if (dTime >= 1.5f)
            {
                aTak = true;
                animator.SetTrigger("Host");
                animator.ResetTrigger("Susp");
                dTect = false;
            }
        }
        if (aTak == true)
        {
            Attack();
        }
    }

    public void Attack()
    {
        //fill in whatever you want it to do when attacking
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            dTime = 0;
            dTect = true;
            sPect = false;
            animator.SetTrigger("Susp");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            dTime = 0;
            sPect = true;
            dTect = false;
            aTak = false;
        }
    }
```

I believe the problem was with the timers not adding up correctly and not setting the bools to the right state. Also I would highly recommend looking into using an enum for states instead of booleans, they're a lot easier to use cause you don't have to turn off every other state to change it. Good luck with your game and let me know if this wasn't the solution or if you have any other questions :)